# Grails/Spock Unit testing with sessionFactory

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

```
@Transactional
class service {
    def sessionFactory 

    def doSomething(buildings) {
        buildings.each {
            def building ->
                building.owner = 'John'
                building.save(failOnError:true)
        }

        def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        checkNotNull(session)
        session.flush()
    }
}
```

This code make all the building owners to 'John' or none

but the in the Unit testing code, i cannot use @Mock(SessionFactory), because it is not in the grails env. if i Mock(SessionFactory), code like:

```
    given:
    service.sessionFactory = Mock(SessionFactory)
    Session session = Mock(Session)
    service.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() >> session

    Building building = new Building(communityId: 199).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    when:
    service.doSomething(Lists.newArrayList(building)
    building = Building.findById(building.id)

    then:
    building.owner == 'John'
```

However the building.owner is NULL, i think the session flush should not mock

So, what should i do? thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you are actually storing the values in database and testing the result, you should do integration test. You can do that by extending the `IntegrationSpec` or using the `@TestMixin(IntegrationTestMixin)` if you just want to extends from `Specification`:

```
class ServiceSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def "service test"() {
        given:
        Building building = new Building(communityId: 199).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        when:
        service.doSomething([building])
        building = Building.findById(building.id)

        then:
        building.owner == 'John'        
    }
}
```

Just make sure that you are defining the "test" environment correctly in your DataSource.groovy.